# How can i create an account on oracle cloud application?

Tags: oracle, saas, bi-publisher

I need to create an account on oracle cloud applications , i am studying a course of BI publisher and i need to try examples by myself , i searched for something to help me but no result .
Is that possible creating account on oracle cloud applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike salesfore, Oracle does NOT provide absolute free developer accounts for its cloud applications. You will have to sign up for an account with your credit card, and can close the account after your training is done.